# Does Google OAuth work inside an iframe?

Tags: oauth, google-oauth

I was wondering if Google's OAuth works from within an iframe? I tried looking this up but couldn't find exactly what I was looking for so any insight would be appreciated!

Background: When I use my web-app with Google OAuth inside a normal window it's fine but when I try it inside an iframe it just takes me to a blank page instead of letting me select which account I'd like to sign in with.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I am not familiar with the inner workings of iframe but i know that the Oauth screen is going to require cookies.   It may be preventing that.

Comment: it will depend on the origin of the iframe. If it's the same as the parent which has been registered as a permitted origin, it should work. However there is no guarantee that the gapi library will work correctly, you'll need to try it.

Comment: Hello @Tim, any luck on your question, I am looking out for the same. ?

Comment: @MaheshKumaran This was from quite some time ago but I recall not being able to use it from within an iframe the way I wanted it to. The reason being is that you cannot transfer data from the iframe to the parent